# Compile export for import and window use

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

How do I create file in typescript that can be both imported from another module and used with `<script src=""/>`. E.g.:

**index.ts**:

```
export class A {

   echo() {
     console.log('a');
   }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
  },
}
```

How do I generate output like this:

```
class A { 
   echo() {
      console.log('a');
   }
}
if (typeof exports !== 'undefined) {
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    exports.A = A;
// don't expose to global scope if module is imported via webpack or etc
} else if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    window.A = A
}
```

Also I want my compiler to generate `index.d.ts` with:

```
export declare class A {
   echo()
}
```

What did I try:

- I can't use exports inside of `if` in `.ts` files
- I can't define variable exports and use custom if.
- I tried different `module` in `tsconfig.json`:

I also thought I could create 2 tsconfig and run tsc 2 times. But I can't generate js file without some export method when my `index.ts` contains `export`. E.g. with `"module"="none"` it still generates

```
 Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });`
```

and I get

```
exports is not defined
```

The only way I see atm is to add webpack and create a separate file `main.js` that has import statement and `window` assigment. But it has a lot of overhead code compared to library size.

Comment: checkout https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output#outputlibrarytarget

Comment: @DanielPérez it doesn't matter what target I generate, webpack adds a lot of overhead, whether it's `var` or `assign` whenever you use webpack it will add its code https://gist.github.com/akoidan/963890be913d79360dbc896c06e99bb9 I have a single file library I don't need dependency management from webpack

Comment: what about rollup https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup, `rollup main.js --format umd --name "myBundle" --file bundle.js`

Comment: So I run it via ts compiler first? @DanielPérez so what format should I specify? if I specify `umd` it requires umd dependency to be in global scope. If i specify `iife` it doesn't remove exports from source code, all it does is just wraps the source code in anonymous function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [rollup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup) with `iife` mode:

```sh
$ npm i rollup typescript rollup-plugin-typescript rollup-plugin-uglify
$ ./node_modules/.bin/rollup -c rollup.config.js
```

**rollup.config.js**:

```
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript';
import { uglify } from "rollup-plugin-uglify";

export default {
    input: './index.ts',
    output: {file: './browser.js', format: 'iife', name: 'myBundle'},
    plugins: [
        typescript(),
        uglify()
    ]
}
```

**index.ts**:

```
// index.ts
export class A {
  echo() {
    console.log("a");
  }
}
```

output **browser.js**:

```js
var myBundle=function(o){"use strict";var n=(t.prototype.echo=function(){console.log("a")},t);function t(){}return o.A=n,o}({});
```